# How can select next row data into the current row result in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Having a MySQL table with such data

```
code     |       amount      |       effective_from
a        |       12000       |       7/1/2021
b        |       12000       |       8/1/2021
d        |       12000       |       7/1/2021
c        |       9000        |       6/1/2021
b        |       12000       |       15/1/2021
c        |       1800        |       10/1/2021
b        |       4500        |       21/1/2021
a        |       4500        |       12/1/2021
c        |       4500        |       20/1/2021
d        |       4500        |       7/1/2021
a        |       4500        |       17/1/2021
```

Now that I want to extract data with an additional column as below:

```
code     |       amount      |       effective_from |effective_to
a        |       12000       |       7/1/2021       |   12/1/2021
a        |       4500        |       12/1/2021      |   17/1/2021
a        |       4500        |       17/1/2021      |   (null)
b        |       12000       |       8/1/2021       |   15/1/2021
b        |       12000       |       15/1/2021      |   21/1/2021   
b        |       4500        |       21/1/2021      |   (null)
c        |       9000        |       6/1/2021       |   10/1/2021
c        |       1800        |       10/1/2021      |   20/1/2021
c        |       4500        |       20/1/2021      |   (null)
```

The column `effective_to` data should come from the `effective_from` of the immediate row with an **effective from** date greater than the current effective from if available else return `null`.

Is there any workaround or I restructure my database?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a cumulative `min()` with a `range` specification:

```
select t.*,
       min(effective_from) over (order by effective_from
                                 range between interval 1 day following and unbounded following
                                ) as effective_to
from t;
```

Note:  This assumes that `effective_from` is a date with no time component.  If there is a time component, you might want `interval 1 second` instead.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94686311db38fc2a94cce15fb903f713) is a db<>fiddle.

In most circumstances like this, there would be an "entity" column where you would want the next value for that entity.  In that case, the typical logic is `LEAD()` rather than a cumulative minimum.